# Check if subroutine exists in Perl

Tags: perl

I would like to check if a subroutine exists before calling it. For example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @names=qw (A B);

for (@names) {
  my $sub=\&{"print$_"};
  if (exists &{$sub}) {
    &$sub();
  }
}

sub printA {
  print "hello A\n";
}
```

However this code does not work. It gives error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::printB
```

I know that I can use `eval`,

```
for (@names) {
  my $sub=\&{"print$_"};
  eval {
    &$sub();
  };
  if ($@) {
    print "$_ does not exist..\n";
  }
}
```

This is fine, but it would be nice to know why the first code did not work?

Comment: Because you call a method that not exists. What do you expected n this case?

Comment: Ok I see :) I hoped to check if it existed..

Comment: Personally my recommendation would be to *not* check whether it exists. Just call it. If it doesn't exist, this will result in an exception, which can be caught using `eval` or [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny). An explicit `exists` check will break down e.g. if the sub is provided via the `AUTOLOAD` mechanism.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're trying to make a reference before knowing whether or not the sub exists. Check that first using the *name* of the subroutine in the call to `exists`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach (qw(A B)) {
    my $name = 'print' . $_;
    if (exists &{$name}) {
        my $s = \&{$name};
        $s->();
    }
}

sub printA {
    print "hello A"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
my $sub = main->can("print$_");
if ($sub) {
  $sub->();
}
```

From [`perldoc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html)

> can checks if the object or class has a method called METHOD . If it does, then it returns a reference to the sub. If it does not, then it returns undef. This includes methods inherited or imported by $obj , CLASS , or VAL .

Comment: That looks for a method, not a subroutine. It only makes sense to use `my $sub = main->can("print$_");` is you follow up with `main->$sub();`, and that's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @ikegami `main->$sub()` doesn't make sense while `$sub->()` does (hint $_[0]). Btw, feel free to improve the answer.

Answer (score 3):

if you change the code to:

```
for (@names) {
  my $sub="print$_";
  no strict 'refs';
  if (exists &{$sub}) {
    &$sub;
  }
}
```

The method will call only if it exists.

Answer (score -1):

It's almost certainly better to avoid calling subroutines by string in this way. One easy way to do so would be to use subroutine refs.

```
my %prints = (
  'printA' => \&printA,
  'printB' => \&printB,
);
for (@names) {
  my $printName = "print$_";
  if($prints{$printName}) {
    $prints{$printName}->();
  }
  else {
    warn "Invalid print: $printName";
  }
}
```